# Problems with npm registry during Angular 8 update

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install, npm-config

We are currently updating an Angular 7.2 version on Angular 8.

After running the command `sudo ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`, there are many error messages like the following:

> 404 Not Found - GET https://my-company-registry/leaflet

We use a company registry, which I renamed in my link above.

So far, everything has worked, but suddenly the error messages mentioned above occured. Even with simple `npm install package-name` commands.

I've already checked my .npmrc file inside my project or the global one and tried commands like `npm cache clear --force` or `npm cache verify`.

I also deleted my node-modules folder and tried to install everything again. Doesn't work..

If I try to use `sudo npm update npm -g` I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://my-company-registry/npm
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'npm@^6.9.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/codehan/.npm/_logs/2019-09-20T12_51_34_857Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command and enter your registry:- `npm config edit`,

Or if it is not work than try to run this command `npm config set registry <registry url>`